# Centos web camera, fast application for snapshot?

Tags: centos, ffmpeg, camera, snapshot

I'm using ffmpeg for taking snapshots / still images with web cameras. I'm going to use several web cameras to take photos at the same time or one after the other (timelapse). It's important for me that this process completes as quick as possible so that the time lapse photographs are not interfered with. Right now, I'm using ffmpeg like this:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 1280x960 -i /dev/video0 -q:v 0 -b:v 10000k -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 cam1.jpg -y
```

At the moment, I feel it's a little bit slow, takes about 1-3 seconds to complete photo. Is there a faster application or any other suggestions to make it faster?

Running: CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 - 64bit

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I guess I have to test and see what's fastest. :/ Or maby I could stream video with all the cameras at the same time and grab a frame from the stream. Like you said, a lot of the delay is probably in start of hardware...